# How can I change the link?

Tags: opencart

I'm using OpenCart v1.5.6.3

Question: How can I change the link? I don't want to SEO for link. I want to change the names in the link.

Example:

Original OpenCart Link: index.php?route=product/product&product_id=46

I want to: index.php?rota=urun/urun&kodu=46

Can we change it? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but is going to need a lot of work. You're going to have to rewrite all of the links throughout the store to use `urun/urun` as the route and `koda` as the `product_id` value. You're then going to have to create a new folder in the controllers called `urun`, create the file `urun.php` in there and copy the code from the product controller into there. Once you've done that, you'll need to rename the controller class from `ControllerProductProduct` to `ControllerUrunUrun`. So in answer to your question, yes it is possible but is probably far more work than you need to do. You'll also have issues with third party extensions that generate product links. Honestly, you'd be better off just using SEO URL's